# AngularJS 'controller as' and form.$valid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I want to check if a form is valid inside an angular controller. This seems straightforward when using $scope, but I can't get it to work with the 'controller as' syntax.

When I attempt to access form.$valid I get the error message *"Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined"*.

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/w54i1bZVD8UMhxB4L2JX?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="demoControllerAs" ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <form name="contactForm" novalidate>
    <p>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="main.email" required />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" ng-model="main.message" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-click="main.submit()" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('demoControllerAs', []);

app.controller('MainController', [function () {
    var main = this;

    main.submit = function () {
        var isValid = main.contactForm.$valid;
        console.log(isValid);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do as @ons-jjss suggested but if you prefer not to inject `$scope` into you controller, then just change your `form` name as

```
<form name="main.contactForm" novalidate>
```

and it'll work like a charm.

Comment: This solution is not intuitive. You are already using $scope in template. You should inject $scope to controller instead of prefixing a form name with weird names such as "main", "$ctrl" or "$vm".

Comment: Yes.. you got it.

Comment: @ismailarilik what's intuitive is matter of perspective, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644370/1061668

Answer (score 4):

You need to use in this way: `$scope.contactForm.$valid`

**EDIT**

To work the above syntax, $scope needs to be inhjected in controller.

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
  //code 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. $scope is not defined. http://plnkr.co/edit/HIwmTvLs0wg6Kt7244vM?p=preview

Comment: I guess you did not inject $scope. app.controller('MainController', function($scope) { //code }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `main.contactForm` in form name attribute then it's solved.
See this

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/us8MKU3LZ7pnLV66xIrv?p=preview`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your form as a parameter to function submit as  **ng-click="main.submit(contactForm)**

and then validate it in controller method