# How to $apply() if not using $scope in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, I'm using `this` instead of `$scope` to save variables and functions, and using controller alias in the HTML to access.

In this case, how to can I update my view, do something like `$digest()` or `$apply()` of `$scope`?

Or is necessary inject `$scope` to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason you're avoiding `$scope`? It's used for data binding between the view and the controller.

Comment: Using `this` has nothing to do with saving variables and functions. Would be same number of variables if you used `$scope`

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm not avoiding `$scope` specifically, just trying fallow the @john_papa style guide (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers)

Comment: @SterlingArcher not necessarily if using `controllerAs` ... don't need to inject it for all controllers

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is, "why do I need to use `$digest()` or `$apply()`?" The need to use those should be very rare.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm using `Q` to manage my promise (`Q.all()`), but when I setting the return value in `then` function, is not update my view, so I'm finding some solution for this.

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30644370/2495283

Comment: provide some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `controllerAs` way have nothing to do with `$scope` in the controller. It's a pattern to avoid contact between `$scope` and the template and also improve readability. However, even though you are using `controllerAs` syntax, you can inject `$scope` on your controller with no problems. That's what `controllerAs` is about, use the `$scope` for propper tasks such as `$scope.$apply`, but not as a view model.

It's not a bad practice injecting the `$scope` even though you're using `controllerAs`. But it would be a bad practice if you use `$scope` to work like a view model. Anyhow, even if you don't inject, `$scope` will exists somehow in the controller internals, it's part of a controller. The aproach of `controllerAs` is to separate the role of view model from the `$scope`. In the end the view model become a part of the scope but it's isolated from the rest of `$scope`'s features.

Comment: So is not bad practice inject `$scope` just for update my view, in this case?

Comment: It's not a bad practice inject `$scope` even though you're using `controllerAs`. But it would be a bad practice if you use `$scope` to work like a view model.

Comment: Thanks you so so much!

Comment: That's right! You should adjust your question pointing to the real problem we discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

@Lai32290 Good job adopting the `controllerAs` convention!  It saves on headaches and makes things much clearer with nested scopes!  As for your question, you cannot avoid the use of `$scope` for the purposes of calling `$digest` or `$apply`.  Remember though that behind the scenes, angularjs still attaches your `controllerAs` to the `$scope`, so it's still there.

You'll need to use it when events occur outside of angular's lifecycle - such as with sockets or events from other external libaries.

http://www.codelord.net/2015/11/11/angular-controlleras-when-should-you-use-scope/