# Trying to use controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented auto-complete feature, now I am trying to integrate into my main application. This is the controller function which I designed.

```
(function() {
      'use strict';
      angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

      function DemoCtrl($http) {
        this.querySearch = function (query) {
           return $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/autocomplete/' + escape(query)).then(function(result) {
              return result.data;
            });
        }
      }
    })();
```

This is my HTML for the first scenario:

```
<div class="autocompletedemoFloatingLabel" ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" ng-app="MyApp" layout="column" ng-cloak="">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <form name="searchForm" ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
            <div layout-gt-sm="row">
            <md-input-container flex="">
            </md-input-container>

            <md-autocomplete md-floating-label="" 
                            flex="" 
                            md-item-text="item.Symbol"
                            md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" 
                            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                            md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" 
                            md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" 
                            md-input-name="autocompleteField" 
                            required="">
              <input>
              <md-item-template>
                <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.Symbol+" - "+item.Name+" ("+item.Exchange+")"}}</span>
              </md-item-template>
              <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite movie.</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
              </div>
            </md-autocomplete>
          </input>
          </div>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Now the application currently contains controller in this format:

```
var app = angular.module("assign8", ["ngAnimate"]);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.myValue=false;
$scope.myValue_sec = false; 
});
```

I am very new to angular, I am unable to map the first format to the second one. Kindly let me know how can I map first to second. TIA.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have an API using which I send suggestions back to the front end. The first controller does that job for me. While the second one is used for switching frames. Ng-show, Ng-hide. I am using Angular 1.5.5. Hope that clears it up. The problem is I dont understand how function() is being used in first line of first format. Second seems more intuitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs "Controller as" or "$scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641478/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the confusion lies. The two scenarios are very similar.

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    this.querySearch = function (query) { ... }
});
```

Comment: <script>
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
app.controller("DemoCtrl", function ($http) {
    this.querySearch = function (query) 
    { 
        return $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/autocomplete/' + escape(query)).then(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        });
    }
});

</script>          I did this change, still doesnt work. I am really sorry but I am still trying to learn angular

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't useful. Please be more specific about the problem (in your question as well as here), and use code formatting for legibility (backquotes in comments).

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir, I was missing ngAnimate file hence the issue. Have a good day.

Comment: Then you should delete the question or provide a correct answer to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two manners to make the binding in AngularJS.

1. **The controller as** that is what is done in the first format, you can see `DemoCtrl as ctrl` in html the ctrl variable represent your controller, in your controller, you see `this`, every attribut of this can be accessed via `ctrl` in html. for example: `ctrl.myAttribut`.
2. The second manner is the use of `$scope` service. that is what is done in the second format. every attribut of `$scope` can be accessed in html as long as the corresponding controller is called. For example: if in your controller you have `$scope.myAttribut`, in your html you can access like this `{{myAttribut}}`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("MyApp");
app.controller("DemoCtrl", function ($http) {
    this.querySearch = function (query) 
    { 
          return $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/autocomplete/' + escape(query)).then(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        });
    }
});
</script>
```